# How I can record stream radio in Linux?

Tags: audio, streaming

How can I record a radio stream in Linux like the screamer in Windows? Does anyone have any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Are you talking about radio from an FM receiver, or radio as a stream over the Internet? If the latter, what protocol does it use?

Answer (score 21):

### GUI

#### Audacity

If you want a GUI to do this you can do it using Audacity.

*excerpt from [wiki](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/help/faq_i18n?s=recording&i=streaming)*

> In the drop-down menu on Audacity's Device Toolbar, choose “Wave Out”
>   or “Stereo Mix” as the input source. (The exact name may be different,
>   depending on your computer's sound drivers). On Windows, if you don't
>   have a “Wave Out” or “Stereo Mix” option, or if it won't record, go to
>   the system Control Panel and try to enable this option there. For
>   instructions see: [Using the Control Panel](http://audacityteam.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mixer_Toolbar_Issues#Using_the_Control_Panel) on the Wiki.

#### Streamtuner

You can also install [streamtuner](http://www.nongnu.org/streamtuner/) to browse radio stations.

```
# Debian/Ubuntu
$ apt-get install streamtuner

# Fedora/CentOS/RHEL
$ yum install streamtuner
```

*screenshot of streamtuner*

[image: ss of streamtuner]

### commandline

You can install [streamripper](http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/) like so:

```
# Debian/Ubuntu
$ sudo apt-get install streamripper

# Fedora/CentOS/RHEL
$ sudo yum install streamripper
```

**example**

To download a stream simply do the following:

```
$ streamripper <url>
```

This will save each stream into a .mp3 file.

### References

- [How to record rip streaming net radio in Ubuntu Debian Linux easy steps](http://myubuntutech.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-record-streaming-net-radio-in.html)

Comment: Hi! I realize this is pretty old response, but are you sure there is port for CentOS available? I get `No package streamripper available`

Comment: @katit - there was when I wrote this answer. I only ever used Fedora/CentOS systems so I'm sure there was.

Answer (score 19):

With curl from the terminal, for example:

```
curl --output ~/Downloads/Radio/CostaDelMar.mp3 http://sc-costadelmar.1.fm:10156
```

Useful options are `--max-time <seconds>` and `--max-filesize <bytes>`.

Comment: In case your stream redirects before playing, use the `-L` flag to have curl follow the Location header (where the redirect is).

Answer (score 4):

A tip related to answer of user170267: You can avoid overwriting previous recording by making use of date&time for file name:

```
 curl --output ~/Downloads/Radio/CostaDelMar_$(date '+%F_%T').mp3 http://sc-costadelmar.1.fm:10156
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `ffmpeg`. Example:

`ffmpeg -i "http://audio.wbhm.org:8000/live.mp3" out.mp3`

To record a particular program you can do the following:

Set a cron job. For example:
`20 11 * * 0 /path/sermon-recording.sh`

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
timeout 65m ffmpeg -i http://briarwood.primcast.com:5182 Sermon_${today}.wav > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I use the `timeout` command to end recording after a certain amount of time. I redirect the output to `/dev/null` to avoid getting a system mail message with the output.

Comment: To set a ffmpeg timeout (see script) it is probably better to use the '`t` option: `ffmpeg -t 3900 -i http://briarwood.primcast.com:5182 Sermon_${today}.wav > /dev/null 2>&1` (3900 = 65m). For me the script, as is now, didn't work. However, the answer fits my needs the best. Thank you.

Comment: I did not realize the `-t` flag would work for that. Nice. Thanks. That URL is now dead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with screamer, but it sounds like **streamripper** is what you want.  It may already be available in your distro or you can get it at http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Check my radio:

Example [WeFunkRadio](http://www.wefunkradio.com/playlaunch/radio).

For the first download playlist and get server address & port:

```
# http://www.wefunkradio.com/play/shoutcast.pls
# cat shoutcast.pls 
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=2
File1=http://wefunkhub.com/radiodrops/introdrop-keithmurray2.mp3
File2=http://stream-90.shoutcast.com:80/wefunk_radio_mp3_64kbps
```

This is the address of server: **http://stream-90.shoutcast.com:80**

To play stream:

```
# mplayer "http://stream-90.shoutcast.com:80"
```

To save stream:

```
# wget -O stream.mp3 "http://stream-90.shoutcast.com:80"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Audio-recorder](https://launchpad.net/~audio-recorder) is another very simple option. Full instructions [here](https://itsfoss.com/record-streaming-audio/).

First install from repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:audio-recorder/ppa
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall audio-recorder
```

Then, select built-in audio output as source:

[image]

Finally, select quality, location, file name, and just start recording.

Notice this will record everything coming from your computer (e.g. sounds from new emails, etc). So make sure everything else is off. This is surely the biggest drawback of the method.